# how to use Snackbar.make(view, Str_Msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT) in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-snackbar

[image]None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
`make(View, CharSequence, Int)` defined in `android.support.design.widget.Snackbar
make(View, Int, Int)` defined in `android.support.design.widget.Snackbar`

```
fun showError(Str_Msg: String) {
    toolbar!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    if (fragment != null) fragment!!.dismiss()

    mActivity!!.window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN)
    snackbar = Snackbar.make(cl_main, Str_Msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .setAction(getString(R.string.lbl_retry)) { }

    snackbar!!.show()
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `cl_main` and `Str_Msg`?

Comment: var cl_main: CoordinatorLayout? = null 
and Str_Msg string veriable
@pete code edit above..

Comment: `cl_main` is nullable and `make(View, CharSequence, Int)` requires `cl_main` to be non-nullable. Quickfix: `make(cl_main!!, Str_Msg ...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cl_main` is `nullable` and `make(View, CharSequence, Int)` requires `cl_main` to be `non-nullable`.

Quickfix: `make(cl_main!!, Str_Msg ...)`

Thanks for @Pete